# How to minus something from every value in array c#

Tags: c#

I would like to ask how to minus some value from all values in an array c#?

```
List<int> array = new List<int>();
array.Add(4,5,3)
array minus 1;
for (int z = 0; z < N; z++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(array[z]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

In output I would like to have this: 3,4,2

Actually I would like to do it in a way that I can work with the changed array not just to print out array minus 1.

Comment: What keeps you from subtracting 1 at array[z]?

Comment: see my answer it should update your array with new subtracted value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to rename the variable first, a list of integers with a name `array` is not good. so let me call the variable as `ListInt`. instead of using `-1` it is better to use a variable called `someValue`. now see the code and how it works:

```
List<int> ListInt = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int someValue = -1;
ListInt = ListInt.Select(x => x - someValue).ToList();
// now the ListInt contains all the values as required
// Print the values using
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",ListInt));
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiple approaches:

a plain foreach-loop:

```
foreach(int i in array) 
    Console.WriteLine(i - 1);
```

a for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
   Console.WriteLine(array[i] - 1);
```

`List.ForEach`:

```
array.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i - 1));
```

`LINQ`:

```
var arrayMinusOne = array.Select(i => i - 1);
foreach(int i in arrayMinusOne) 
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

You can use this `arrayMinusOne` query multiple times (but note that it will be executed every time you use it). Or you could create a new collection with `arrayMinusOne.ToList()` or `ToArray`. If you want to modify the original list you can use the for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
    array[i] = array[i] - 1;
```

or reassign `arrayMinusOne.ToList()` to the `array` variable. Note that a list is not an array.

Comment: I´m sorry I just meant something slightly different.

Comment: @Sam: i've tried to cover all cases, look at the 
last section f.e. `arrayMinusOne.ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

Following your style to help you understand, this will display what you want:

```
for (int z = 0; z < array.Length; z++)
     Console.WriteLine(array[z]-1);
```

But this will actually subtract 1 from the data before displaying the resulted data:

```
for (int z = 0; z < array.Length; z++)
    array[z]--;

for (int z = 0; z < array.Length; z++)
    Console.WriteLine(array[z]);
```

Comment: Sorry I wanted to substarct 1 before printing array so that I could work on it further

Comment: @sam then the next block of my answer does that for you. It subtracts one  from every value in your array (`array[z]--` is the same as `array[z] -= 1` and same as `array[z] = array[z] - 1`). Then you can apply anything to the result data (like display)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> array = new List<int>();
array.Add(2);
array.Add(3);
array.Add(4);
for (int z = 0; z < array.Count; z++)
{
    array[z] = array[z] - 1;
}
Console.WriteLine(array[0]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: what is `array minus 1;`?

Answer (score 0):

*Linq* solution:

```
List<int> array = new List<int>() {
  4, 5, 3,
};

// "3, 4, 2"
Console.Write(String.Join(", ", array.Select(item => item - 1)));

Console.ReadLine();
```

In case you want to put each item on the separate line

```
// 3
// 4
// 2
Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, array.Select(item => item - 1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is in VB.Net, but have the logic:

```
Dim array As New List(Of Integer)()
    array.Add(4)
    array.Add(5)
    array.Add(3)
    Dim resta = -1
    For index = 0 To array.Count - 1
        array(index) = array(index) - 1
        Console.WriteLine(array(index))
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Thank you, but i wanted something different