# How I can apply operators "/" and "-" for type list<double> and double?

Tags: c#, list

I wanna do math calculation for *every components* of a `list<double>` (`TransitTime`) in a class, but I don't know how!
the (`MaaTransitTime`) and (`FlTransitTime`) *aren't list*.

```
public static List<double> TransitTime { get; set; }
public static double MaaTransitTime { set; get; }
public static double FlTransitTime { set; get; }

public static List<double> CalculateSonicPorosity()
{
    return (TransitTime-MaaTransitTime)/(FlTransitTime-MaaTransitTime);
}
```

the **compile time error** is:

> Operator "-" cannot be applied to operands of type List and double.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to minus something from every value in array c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030075/how-to-minus-something-from-every-value-in-array-c-sharp)

Comment: « for every components of a list » *for every* is called **`foreach`** in C#. Use it to iterate over your list. *Plenty* of examples available. Good luck.

Comment: `TransitTime-MaaTransitTime` The first is a **list** of doubles. The second is a **singular** double. What are you expecting that code to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When querying, you can try *Linq*:

```
  public static List<double> CalculateSonicPorosity() =>
    TransitTime.Select(time => (time - MaaTransitTime) / (FlTransitTime - MaaTransitTime)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct support in c# for what you try to achieve.

If there is a lot of math to do with your lists, you can wrap your list in another object like below:

```cs
public class ListWrapper
{
    private List<double> list;

    public ListWrapper(List<double> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public static ListWrapper operator -(ListWrapper a, double b)
    {
        return a.list.Select(x => x - b).ToList();
    }
}
```

Note that this is only a template and there are more methods missing (e.g. you need to implement operators for both combination of parameters and you need an accessor for your list)

Answer (score 1):

That's because a `List<double>` is of a different type than a `double` and there is no suitable operator `-` between the two.

You need to get a `double` from the `List` in order to use the operator `-` with another `double`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to overload operators for two new operations: subtraction between a `List<double>` and a double, and division between two `List<double>`.

You can create a new class that's either a wrapper for the list like in user1781290's answer or directly inherit from List. Then you can overload operators in that created class.

```
public class TransitTime : List<double>{

    public TransitTime() : base(){
    }

    public static TransitTime operator - (TransitTime c1, double c2)  
    {  
        // Here we implement subtraction as subtracting c2 from every member of c1
        TransitTime endTimes = new TransitTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < c1.Count; i++){
            endTimes.Add(c1[i] - c2);
        }
        return endTimes;
    }

    public static TransitTime operator / (TransitTime c1, TransitTime c2)  
    {  
        // Here we implement division as dividing every member of c1 by every member of c2
        TransitTime endTimes = new TransitTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < c1.Count; i++){
            endTimes.Add(c1[i] / c2[i]);
        }
        return endTimes;
    }  
}
```

Here's an example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/BwucL3